# T-SQL Replace "cyrillic symbols" returns '????'

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, encoding, replace

I have a function that converts CSV list to nvarchar(max) records in table. I have noticed it is not working with cyrillic and the problem is this replace here:

```
DECLARE @XML xml = N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@List, ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>'
```

How to make the replace to work with cyrillic symbols? For example 'тест'.

@List is NVARCHAR(MAX) and I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Your query [works just fine](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/80293). Are you sure that `@List` is `nvarchar`?

Comment: Yes, it is NVARCHAR(MAX). It gives me only ???? every time. I try do use the 'COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS' and cast the value, but nothing changed. Also when I executed "SELECT 'Тест'" it gives me ??? too

Comment: I can't, because @List is variable. With N'Тест' it works fine, but I need to use variable.

Comment: How is `@List` assigned its initial value - you haven't shown that bit, and it's almost certainly *that* assignment where the characters are getting lost.

Comment: It is originally assigned as function parameter, but for testing I am just "hard coding" its value as DECLARE @List AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='Тест'.

Comment: Where, as people have repeatedly pointed out, you've failed to use `N'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `N''` notation is used to declare Unicode string literals. If you define a variable NVARCHAR, it is automatically Unicode-enabled (so there is no need (or rather: no way) to additionally declare the `N` for @variables - it is part of the string literal).

Since you get Cyrillic characters in `SELECT N'тест'`, you should check where the variable @List is assigned, and what it's value is.

Not sure how your CSV parser handles Unicode characters, but the source of your problem may be

- not handling file encodings
- assigning to a VARCHAR column or variable before assigning to @List

Comment: I have scripted the function and pass the value directly. It is nvarchar(max) as I said. If I executed just the following statement it gives me '????' too: SELECT REPLACE(CAST('Тест' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS , ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') . What is more strange is that only "Select 'тест'" do no work too.

Comment: you need the leading N: SELECT N'тест'

Comment: Yes, you were right. The issue was caused because I am making dynamic SQL but in which, I am not using the N' symbol. Then the value was incorrectly given to the function and @MikaelEriksson was right too that the issue was not in the function. Thanks for help all.

Answer (score 1):

Are you defining your `@List` variable as nvarchar? Replace will work fine with nvarchars

```
declare @list nvarchar(50) = N'те,ст'
select @list
DECLARE @XML xml = N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@List, ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>'
```

Comment: The problem is not in the above code - it must be in how you are populating the `@list` variable